# Name for "read-only" user on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, terminology

Is there a name for or something to reference Stack Exchange users that only they look and don't collaborate or provide knowledge (ie. answers)?

Comment: I think we call them "most users".

Comment: Did you mean "read-only" (that would be never posting) or specifically not posting answers?

Answer (score 10):

Such person is often called a [lurker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lurker).

> In Internet culture, a lurker is typically a member of an online community who observes, but does not actively participate.

Comment: Or a leech. Leech is also a word for folks like this.

Comment: That doesn't sound very nice @Won't :)

Comment: @Won't - Torrent much?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in English learners SE?